# CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe requires Windows Firewall prompt. But why?

Tags: sockets, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Does anyone know where I can find documentation (or actual source) describing what ports and protocols are actually used by the CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe on Windows? When the CefSharp embedded browser is loaded, a Windows Firewall prompt permission dialog is displayed. This firewall prompt is fairly scary and it would be better if our installer created the rules automatically. But I would like to open up only what's needed.

I see that the rules created when the user is prompted basically open up all communication via TCP and UDP over *any* port. But it seems like the only communication required is between the main exe and CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess on the same box. (Why open *any* external ports?)

However, the interesting thing is that even if you **don't allow** the firewall rule creation, the embedded browser appears to work - and the subprocesses are still launched and appear to be executing properly (from observing in Task Manager).

I posted this question here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3075, and got referred to here: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php, but my question on this topic was rejected as "off topic" by the newsgroup administrator.

I also tried building and running the CefSharp code (specifically, the `CefSharp.Wpf.Example`), but the app crashed on load. I guess I need to debug this more. Looking at the source code, it was difficult for me to identify where the TCP or UDP socket listening code is actually invoked.

Anyway, to summarize, I'm trying to avoid this prompt (by adding the firewall entries at install-time), but I don't want to incur more risk by opening more than needed.

Reflecting more on this, it seems like a potential security issue if the default behavior is to open external ports for a process whose job it is to execute code. Perhaps this somehow offsets the security goals of process isolation for the Chromium network service?

Comment: As per my comment https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3075#issuecomment-597299282 all networking is done by a separate process. This is the same behaviour as Chrome/Chromium.  If you look in task manager you'll see Chrome.exe instance with --type=utility. What do you mean by 'it seems like a potential security issue if the default behavior is to open external ports for a process whose job it is to execute code'? The network service is designed to only perform network requests. Have you looked to see what ports Google Chrome has opened?

Comment: If you wish to only open set ports then you'll nedd to determine which features you'll be allowing.  Http/https/webrtc/websockets etc.

Comment: See https://www.chromium.org/developers/technical-discussion-groups for a list of chromium discussion groups, probably  net-dev is the place to ask

Comment: Thanks @amaitland. I understand that CefSharp is operating similarly to Chrome/Chromium. But Chrome does not require the opening of inbound firewall ports. When ports are opened they allow inbound requests FROM OTHER COMPUTERS to be received and executed. This is a potential issue. I guess I'm not clear if this is really needed if communication only needs to happen between the process hosting the CefSharp embedded browser and the CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe. WebSockets do not appear to require opening additional ports. I guess I can't tell what exact code is tripping the firewall prompt

Comment: In looking at code, it appears that the WCF NetNamedPipeBinding may be responsible for this firewall prompt? Just guessing. If I could step through the code, maybe I could see the exact point where the prompt appears.

Comment: To answer your question, Google Chrome only appears to have this firewall entry: "Google Chrome (mDNS-In)" for UDP only on a specific port.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef you can test with the CEF Sample application, you'll get the same prompt. NetNamedPipeBinding is literally a named pipe, there's no network access. 'But Chrome does not require the opening of inbound firewall ports' how did you come to the conclusion CefSharp is asking to open an inbound port?

Comment: When I run my program that uses CefSharp, the Windows Firewall prompt always appears on the first run. If you click Allow or not, two entries are created in your "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" named "cefsharp.browsersubprocess.exe". If you delete these entries, you will be prompted again on next run. It sounds like you believe this is unintentional. But this is the same issue reported here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3075. Anyway, still trying to run the compiled CefSharp example. It builds cleanly, but crashes with a "System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException"

Comment: Oh, 64-bit runs without exception. But, it's not showing this firewall prompt. Curious

Comment: Please test with the CEF Sample application. You'll see the behaviour isn't CefSharp specific. The use of NetNamedPipeBinding is CefSharp specific, that should rule that out. I'm puzzled by the inbound port. I expect you'll need to allow 80, 443 for outbound,  maybe some other ports, I'd start with those. The Firewall prompt is not unexpected as I have stated https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3075#issuecomment-597299282

Comment: Alternatively you can try running the network service in process as I've described https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3075#issuecomment-646581773

Comment: Thanks. I did try that, but it still produced the firewall prompt - except the prompt was not for the subprocess.exe, it was for my own executable. Trying CEF Sample application...

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for bearing with me and guiding me on this. I just realized that the specific page I'm loading appears to be triggering this prompt. It's reproducible in the CEF Sample application and the CefSharp.Wpf.Example when I load the same URL. I don't understand what the page is doing here, but this is at least something I can work with the server devs on. I guess I don't appreciate why Chrome or other browsers don't show the same prompt. But this resolves the issue for me. If you want to post an answer here, I can mark as correct and upvote. Thanks also for making CefSharp possible!

Comment: Perhaps it's multicast DNS prompting for a rule to be added? If you add a rule the same as `Google Chrome (mDNS-In)` does that prevent the dialog? Can you provide a sample url?

Comment: Multicast DNS would explain the inbound udp rule and the 'it still works even if I say no' behaviour.

Comment: @amaitland I sent URL in github thread. Still trying to work with back-end team on exactly what web function is triggering this. Regarding adding the mDNS-In rule, I tried this and it prevented the prompt from appearing. But I also tried deleting that rule while keeping the TCP rule, and it still prevented the prompt from appearing. So, it seems like any rule for the exe will likely prevent the prompt from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on guidance from @amaitland, we landed on two possible solutions:

1. At install time (with Administrator privileges), create a Windows Firewall entry for mDNS tied to the `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe` with UDP port 5353.
2. Disable `mDNS` using: `settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-features", "WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns");` <- **This solution did not work**